# Should an image be able to resize itself in OOP?

Tags: object-oriented, domain-driven-design

I'm writing an app that will have an `Image` entity, and I'm already having trouble deciding whose responsibility each task should be.

First I have the `Image` class. It has a path, width, and other attributes.

Then I created an `ImageRepository` class, for retrieving images with a single and tested method, eg: `findAllImagesWithoutThumbnail()`.

But now I also need to be able to `createThumbnail()`. Who should deal with that? I was thinking about having an `ImageManager` class, which would be an app-specific class (there would also be a third party image manipulation reusable component of choice, I'm not reinventing the wheel).

Or maybe it would be 0K to let the `Image` resize itself? Or let the `ImageRepository` and `ImageManager` be the same class?

What do you think?

Comment: What does Image do so far?

Comment: How do you expect to resize the images?  Are you only ever shrinking images or can you imagine wanting to go back to the full size?

Comment: @WinstonEwert It generates data like the formatted resolution (eg: the string '1440x900'), different URL's, and lets you modify some stats like 'views' or 'votes'.

Comment: @StevenBurnap I consider the original image the most important thing, I only use thumbnails for faster browsing or if the user wants to resize to fit his desktop or something, so they are a separate thing.

Comment: I would make the Image class immutable so that you don't have to defensively copy it when you pass it around.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to solve a non-problem.  There is software designed to resize images already.  So make the images a resource of the application and based on a application setting choose which images to use.

Comment: Is image manipulation your primary domain?

Comment: @andho I don't know. This question arised while developing a website to share images, but I might need these components for other pieces of software in the future.

Answer (score 8):

The question as asked is too vague to have a real answer as it really depends on how the `Image` objects are going to be used.

If you are only using the image at one size, and are resizing because the source image is the wrong size, it might be best to have the read code do the resizing.  Have your `createImage` method take a width/height and then return the image having been resized at that width/height.

If you need multiple sizes, and if memory isn't a concern, it is best to keep the image in memory as originally read and do any resizing at display time.  In such a case, there are a couple different designs you might use.  The image `width` and `height` would be fixed, but you'd either have a `display` method that took a position and a target height/width or you'd have some method taking a width/height that returned an object that whatever display system you are using.  Most drawing APIs I've used let you specify target size at draw time.

If the requirements cause for drawing at a different sizes often enough for performance to be a concern, you could have a method that creates a new image of a different size based on the original.  An alternative would be to have your `Image` class cache different representations internally so that the first time you call `display` with the thumbnail size it does the resizing while the second time it just draws the cached copy it saved from last time.  This uses more memory, but it is rare you'll have more than a few common resizings.

Another alternative is to have a single `Image` class that retains the base image and have that class contain one or more representations.  An `Image` itself wouldn't have a height/width.  Instead, it would start with one `ImageRepresentation` that had a height and width.  You'd draw this representation.  To "resize" an image, you'd ask the `Image` for a representation with certain height/width metrics.  This would cause it to then contain this new representation as well as the original.  This gives you a lot of control over exactly what is hanging around in memory at the cost of extra complexity.

I personally dislike classes that contain the word `Manager` because "manager" is a very vague word that doesn't really tell you much about exactly what the class does.  Does it manage object lifetime?  Does it stand between the rest of the application and the thing it manages?

Comment: "it really depends on how the Image objects are going to be used." This statement isn't really in line with the notion of encapsulation and loose coupling (although it may be taking the principle a little too far in this case). A better point of differentiation would be whether and Image's state meaningfully includes size or not.

Comment: Seems you are talking about a Image Editing application point of view. Not entirely clear if OP wanted this or not huh?

Answer (score 6):

Keep things simple as long as there are only a few requirements, and improve your design when you have to. I guess in most real-world cases there is nothing wrong to start with a design like that:

```
class Image
{
    public Image createThumbnail(int sizeX, int sizeY)
    {
         // ...
         // later delegate the actual resize operation to a separate component
    }
}
```

Things may become different when you need to pass more parameters to `createThumbnail()`, and those parameters need a lifetime of their own. For example, lets assume you are going to create thumbnails for several hundred images, all with some given destination size, resize algorithm or quality. That will mean that you could move the `createThumbnail` to another class, for example, a manager class, or an `ImageResizer` class, where those parameters are passed in by the constructor and so are bound to the lifetime of the `ImageResizer` object.

Actually, I would start with the first approach and refactor later when I really need it.

Comment: well, if I'm delegating the call to a separate component already why not make it a responsibility of a `ImageResizer` class in the first place? When do you delegate a call instead of moving the responsibility to a new class?

Comment: @Songo: 2 possible reasons: (1) the code for delegating to the - perhaps already existing - separate component is not just a simple one-liner, perhaps just a sequence of 4 to 6 commands, thus you need a place to store it. (2) Syntactical sugar / ease of use: it will be just very handsome to write `Image thumbnail = img.createThumbnail(x,y)`.

Comment: +1 aah I see. Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 4):

I think it would have to be part of the `Image` class, as resizing in an external class would require the resizer to know the implementation of the `Image`, thereby violating encapsulation.  I'm assuming `Image` is a base class, and you'll wind up with separate subclasses for concrete image types (PNG, JPEG, SVG, etc).  Therefore, you'll either have to have corresponding resizing classes, or a generic resizer with a `switch` statement that resizes based on the implementation class -- a classic design smell.

One approach might be to have your `Image` constructor take a resource containing the image, and height and width parameters and create itself appropriately.  Then resizing could be as simple as creating a new object using the original resource (cached inside the image) and the new size parameters.  E.g. `foo.createThumbnail()` would simply `return new Image(this.source, 250, 250)`. (with `Image` being the concrete type of `foo`, of course).  This keeps your images immutable and their implementations private.

Comment: I like this solution, but I don't understand why you say that the resizer needs to know the internal implementation of `Image`. All it needs is the source and the target dimensions.

Comment: While I think having an external class doesn't make sense because it would be unexpected, it neither would have to violate encapsulation nor would it require to have a switch() statement when performing a resize. Ultimately an image is a 2d array of something, and you can definitely resize images as long as the interface allows getting and setting individual pixels.

Answer (score 4):

I know that OOP is about encapsulating data and behavior together, but I don't think it's a good idea for an Image to have the resize logic embedded in this case, because an Image doesn't *need* to know how to resize itself to be an Image.

A thumbnail is actually a different Image.  Perhaps you might have a datastructure that holds the relationship between a Photograph and it's Thumbnail (both of which are Images).

I try to divide my programs into things (like Images, Photographs, Thumbnails, etc.) and Services (like PhotographRepository, ThumbnailGenerator, etc.).  Get your data structures right, and then define the services that let you create, manipulate, transform, persist and recover those data structures.  I don't put any more behavior in my data structures than making sure they're created properly and used appropriately.

Therefore, no, an Image shouldn't contain the logic about how to make a Thumbnail.  There should be a ThumbnailGenerator service that has a method like:

```
Image GenerateThumbnailFrom(Image someImage);
```

My bigger data structure might look like this:

```
class Photograph : Image
{
    public Photograph(Image thumbnail)
    {
        if(thumbnail == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("thumbnail");
        this.Thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public Image Thumbnail { get; private set; }
}
```

Of course that might mean you're doing effort you don't want to do while constructing the object, so I would consider something like this OK too:

```
class Photograph : Image
{
    private Image thumbnail = null;
    private readonly Func<Image,Image> generateThumbnail;

    public Photograph(Func<Image,Image> generateThumbnail)
    {
        this.generateThumbnail = generateThumbnail;
    }


    public Image Thumbnail
    {
        get
        {
            if(this.thumbnail == null)
            {
                this.thumbnail = this.generateThumbnail(this);
            }
            return this.thumbnail;
        }
    }
}
```

... in the case where you want a data structure with lazy evaluation.  (Sorry I didn't include my null checks and I didn't make it thread-safe, which is something you'd want if you were trying to mimic an immutable data structure).

As you can see, either of these classes is being built by some kind of PhotographRepository, which probably has a reference to a ThumbnailGenerator that it got through dependency injection.

Comment: I've been told I shouldn't create classes with no behavior. Not sure if when you say 'data structures' you are referring to the classes or something from C++ (is that this language?). The only data structures I know and use are the primitives. The services and DI part is spot on, I might end up doing this.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper: occasionally classes with no behavior are useful or necessary, depending on situation. Those are called *value classes*. Normal OOP classes are classes with hard-coded behavior. Composable OOP classes also have hard-coded behavior, but their structure of their composition can give rise to many behaviors needed by a software application.

Answer (score 3):

You have identified a single functionality you want to implement, so why shouldn't it be separate from everything you have identified so far? That is what the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) would suggest is the solution.

Create an `IImageResizer` interface that allows you to pass in an image and a target size, and which returns a new image. Then create an implementation of that interface. There are actually tons of ways to resize images, so you could even end up with more than one!

Comment: +1 for relevant SRP, but I'm not implementing the actual resizing, that's already delegated to a third party library as stated.

Answer (score 3):

I assume those facts about method, that resizes images:

- It must return new copy of image. You cannot modify the image itself, because it would break other code that has reference to this image.
- It doesn't need access to the internal data of Image class. Image classes usually need to offer public access to those data (or copy of).
- Image resizing is complex and requires many different parameters. Maybe even extensibility points for different resizing algorithms. Passing everything would result in big method signature.

Based on those facts, I would say that there is no reason for Image resizing method be part of Image class itself. Implementing it as static helper method of class would be best.

Comment: Good assumptions. Not sure why it should be a static method though, I try to avoid them for testability.

Answer (score 2):

An Image Processing class might be appropriate (or Image Manager, as you called it).  Pass your Image to a CreateThumbnail method of the Image Processor, for example, to retrieve a thumbnail image.

One of the reasons I'd suggest this route is that you say you're using a 3rd party image processing library.  Taking the resizing functionality out of the Image class itself might make it easier for you to isolate any platform specific or 3rd party code.  So if you can use your base Image class across all platforms/apps, you then dont have to pollute it with platform or library specific code.  That can all be located in the Image Processor.

Comment: Good point. Most people here didn't understand I'm already delegating the most complicated part to a 3rd party library, maybe I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Basically as Doc Brown already said:

Create a `getAsThumbnail()` method for the image class, but this method should actually just delegate the work to some `ImageUtils` class. So it would look something like this:

```
 class Image{
   // ...
   public Thumbnail getAsThumbnail{
     return ImageUtils.convertToThumbnail(this);
   }
   // ...
 }
```

And

```
 class ImageUtils{
   // ...
   public static Thumbnail convertToThumbnail(Image i){
     // ...
   }
   // ...
 }
```

This will allow easier-to-look-at code. Compare the following:

```
Image i = ...
someComponent.setThumbnail(i.getAsThumbnail());
```

Or

```
Image i = ...
Thumbnail t = ImageUtils.convertToThumbnail(i);
someComponent.setThumbnail(t);
```

If the latter one seems good for you, you can also stick to just creating this helper method somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the "Image Domain", you just have the Image object which is immutable and monadic. You ask the image for a resized version and it returns a resized version of itself. Then you can decide whether you want to get rid of the original or keep both.

Now the thumbnail, avatar, etc versions of the Image is another Domain entirely, which can ask the Image domain for different versions of a certain image to give to a user. Usually this domain is also not so huge or generic, so you can probably keep this in application logic.

In a small scale app, I would resize the images at read time. For example I could have a apache rewrite rule that delegates to php a script if the image 'http://my.site.com/images/thumbnails/image1.png', where the file will be retrieved using the name image1.png and resized and stored in 'thumbnails/image1.png'. Then on the next request to this same image, apache will serve the image directly without running the php script. Your question of findAllImagesWithoutThumbnails is automatically answered by apache, unless you need to do statistics?

In a large scale app, I would send the all new images to a background job, which takes care of generating the different versions of the image and saves it in appropriate places. I wouldn't bother creating a whole domain or class as this domain is very unlikely to grow into a terrible mess of spaghetti and bad sauce.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

My recomendation is adding this methods the image class:

```
public Image getResizedVersion(int width, int height);
public Image getResizedVersion(double percentage);
```

The Image object is still inmutable, these methods return a new image.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few great answers already, so I'll elaborate a bit about a heuristics behind the way to identify objects and their responsibilities.

OOP differs from real life in that objects in real life are often passive, and in OOP they are active. And this is a core of [object thinking](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735619654). For example, who would resize an image in real life? A human, which is smart in that respect. But in OOP there are no humans, so objects are smart instead. A way to implement this "human-centric" approach in OOP is utilizing service classes, for example, notorious `Manager` classes. Thus objects are treated as passive data-strcutures. It's not an OOP way.

So there are two options. The first one, creating a method `Image::createThumbnail()`, is already considered. The second one is to create a `ResizedImage` class. It can be a decorator of an `Image` (it depends on your domain whether to preserve an `Image` interface or not), though it results in some encapsulation issues, since `ResizedImage` would have to have an `Image`'s source. But an `Image` would not be overwhelmed with resizing details, leaving it to a separate domain object, acting in accordance with a SRP.